# Function array_pop doesnt shortens an array

Tags: php

i have below table with exactly these 3 values in mysql db

```
+-----+-------+
| bID | book  |
+-----+-------+
|   9 | sajid |
|  10 | Salim |
|  11 | Salim |
+-----+-------+
```

i use this php code to retrieve

```
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","library");
            mysql_select_db("library",$con);
            $sqlb = "SELECT * FROM books";
            $queryb = mysql_query($sqlb);
            while ($resultsb[] = mysql_fetch_object ( $queryb ));
            array_pop ( $resultsb ); 
            print_r($resultsb);
```

and it outputs this array

```
  Array ( 
          [0] => stdClass Object ( [bID] => 9 [book] => sajid ) 
          [1] => stdClass Object ( [bID] => 10 [book] => Salim ) 
      [2] => stdClass Object ( [bID] => 11 [book] => Salim ) 
  )
```

according to php manual "array_pop() pops and returns the last value of the array, shortening the array by one element."
My question is it doesnt shortens my array by 1 element although i do not need to shorten it the array it give me serves my purpose but it is contradiction that php manual says the Array_pop shortens the array by one why doesnt it happens here

regards

AP

Comment: before array_pop your `$resultsb` should have had 4 stdClass objects

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Another point: don't use `mysql` functions, they will be deprecated soon. Replace them with `mysqli` or PDO functions.

Comment: Try a `print_r` *before* you pop...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @deceze i print_r before the array_pop it prints the same array it didnt showed any 4 elements

Comment: when i use mysqli it give me this error  mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,

Comment: You don't see a "`[3] => `" in there?

Comment: @deceze No but when i remove the array_pop there is a value in the select box at the end Notice: Trying to get property of non-Object

Comment: Try a `var_dump` instead of a `print_r` if you have trouble seeing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reach the end of the result set, the fetch function returns FALSE and you store it in the array. The array_pop function removes it from the array, leaving only the items that were fetched from the database.

Comment: Add a call to print_r before the call to array_pop.

Comment: No but when i remove the array_pop there is a value in the select box at the end Notice: Trying to get property of non-Object

Comment: What do you mean by "no but"?

Comment: when i remove the array_pop there is a value in the select box at the end Notice: Trying to get property of non-Object that means now in my select box are 4 values why do i get the 4th one by removing array_pop

Comment: Didn't I just explain that? The 4th value is the booleanffalse that tells you there are no more rows. Calling array_pop removes it.